# How to trigger "press" event in Hammer JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

To trigger click event I use:

```
$("my Ele").trigger('click')
```

And it's working fine.

In this case how to trigger click event?

I am using Hammer.js.

Is there is no option to trigger events?

Kindly help in this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$("my Ele")
    .hammer()
    .on('tap', function(e){
        // do something
    })
```

Comment: Isn’t that the listener, not trigger?

Comment: @Seb didn't he just ask how to trigger the click event?